# How do I get the volume levels from an audio file?

Tags: audio

I need a Linux tool to analyze Audio files for their Loudness. Maybe the average for each 100 milliseconds.

output like: `(0=>-12,100=>-18,200=>-24,300=>-55)`
Any Ideas

Comment: Questions requesting working code written to a specification are off-topic as they are unlikely to benefit anyone else. Instead, describe the problem you're solving and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can give you a quick and hacky solution with `sox` that can be easily installed on any Linux distribution.

`sox in.wav -n trim 0 0.1 stats : newfile : restart 2>&1 | grep 'RMS lev dB' | awk '{ print $4 }'`

This will return RMS levels for each 0.1 second chunk. Change `in.wav` to the input file and `0.1` if you require a different frame length.

Comment: Wow thanks! i will try it

Comment: this works  great!